# Updating more than one bean on submit

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

Using Primefaces 3.1.1.

I am trying to perform two actions on submit of 1 commandButton:

The original form elements are as follows:

```
<p:calendar ... value="#{bean.date1}" />
<p:calendar ... value="#{bean.date2}" />
<h:commandButton value="submit" onchange="TASK" action="#{Bean.saveOrUpdateItem()}" >
</h:commandButton>
```

But now, I would **also** like to achieve the following with the press of that same button:

```
<h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="result" />
</h:commandButton>
<h:outputText id="result" value="#{bean.date3}" />
```

Any pointers on how to deal with that?
I do not want to modify the first Bean.saveOrUpdateItem() and have to create the second bean.

Thank you in advance.

-V

Comment: My guess.. its not possible. Why don't you have a single `commandButton` with only one action `submit`. On click of this, call `saveOrUpdateItem` method as well inside `submit` method?

Comment: Thank you, i will try this and let you know here.

Comment: Hi Vikas, How could I access widgetVar from xhtml (primefaces) page in ManagedBean? I must use the widgetVars to add and then show the result.

Comment: I want to achieve this apaprently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320338/how-to-access-widgets-from-managedbean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [f:actionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/)

```
<h:commandButton value="Submit" id="submit" action="#{myBean0.action}" >
       <f:actionListener binding="#{myBean1.actionListener}"/>
            <f:actionListener binding="#{myBean2.actionListener}"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: Hi, could you provide with an example of the actionListener?

Comment: I want to achieve something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320338/how-to-access-widgets-from-managedbean

Comment: any further explanation would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hi, The answer just shows how to invoke methods in multiple beans when clicking the button. actionListener is just another backing bean method